# Empty results while using python-tesseract's psm 7 to read pdf in Python

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I want to read a pdf which states a name (e.g. Max Müller). The problem is that above the name there is a signature which slighty overlaps with the name. I have tried the tessarcact psm 7 which treats the image as a single text line, but it gives me an empty result.

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\hoffmann\AppData\Local\anaconda3\Library\bin\tesseract.exe'
custom_oem_psm_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 7'
image = Image.open('G:/PraktikantInnen/PRAKTIKANTINNEN/Hoffmann/Read_pdf_Stella/face.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
print(text)
```

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have clarified and edited the question (please see above)